# Jenkinsfile read file and use in a loop

Tags: loops, github, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, readfile

I have a scripted Jenkins pipeline located in Jenkinsfile in Github repo. I need to read some data and use it for my script, for this I have this piece of code:

```
def mydata = [‘val1’, ‘val2’]
mydata.each() {
…
}
```

Now I need to place the data in the .txt file in the same Github repository and read data from that file. The format in the file is:

val1

val2

I tried this way:

```
def tmpval = readFile file: ‘values.txt' 
        env.Mydata = tmpval
        Mydata.each() {
        ......
        }
```

but it doesn’t work as expected, I received
“Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

```
String[] mydata = new File("${WORKSPACE}/values.txt")
mydata.each {
```